# Hibernate exception Query not properly ended

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Getting exception while running this query

```
select COUNT(tl.LOG_ID)AS EVTCOUNT,tl.PRIORITY FROM Customer_? tl Where tl.DEVICE_REPORTED_TIME >= SysDate-90 GROUP BY tl.PRIORITY ORDER BY tl.PRIORITY`
```

Here I am using `query.setLong(0,custId);`

so it will become like `Customer_1`

If I run the above query from SqlDeveloper IDE It is working fine or If I set this value as Statically like `Customer_1` instead of `Customer_?`
It working fine.

Errors:

> WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 933, SQLState: 42000
> ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

What Might be wrong with this query though other queries are running fine?

**Edit**

I am using NamedQueries and I have written this query in a separate xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a parameter in a query like that. Without going into the logic behind this, your best option is to concatenate the query string before creating a query

```
String queryString = "select COUNT(tl.LOG_ID) AS EVTCOUNT,tl.PRIORITY FROM Customer_" + custId + " tl Where tl.DEVICE_REPORTED_TIME >= SysDate-90 GROUP BY tl.PRIORITY ORDER BY tl.PRIORITY";
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
```

**EDIT**

As for NamedQueries, they are compiled when the application is started so I don't think there is a way to change the target entity (table) at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, I removed The NamedQuery and did as you said but now I am getting error as `unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 80 [select COUNT(tl.LOG_ID)AS EVTCOUNT,tl.PRIORITY FROM Customer_1 tl Where tl.DEVICE_REPORTED_TIME >= SysDate-90 GROUP BY tl.PRIORITY ORDER BY tl.PRIORITY`

Comment: `session.createQuery()` expects JPQL, not SQL. If you want to execute SQL, use `session.createSQLQuery()` instead. Note that `@NamedQuery` also expects JPQL, and `@NamedNativeQuery` is used for SQL queries.

Comment: Great without seeing the code Identified what I have done wrong. This was my first time to use Hibernate so got confused..