# Hibernate delete query with cross joins

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to execute a delete query as following:

```
@Modifying
@Query("delete from Document d where d.requestDocument.request.id = :requestId and d.documentType.lookupCode in (:documentTypeLookupCodes)")
Integer deleteByRequestIdAndDocumentTypes(@Param("requestId") Long requestId, @Param("documentTypeLookupCodes") List<String> documentTypeLookupCodes);
```

I am using spring data jpa repositories and when it executes it generates :

```
DELETE FROM sakreg_documents cross join request_docs requestdoc1_ cross join sakreg_doc_type documentty2_ where sakreg_request_id=1111 and (lkp_code in ('IN' , 'OUT'))
```

and throws

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Document Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SAKREG_DOCUMENTS")
public class Document {
      @Id
      @SequenceGenerator(name = "DocumentSequence", sequenceName = "SAKREG_DOCUMENTS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "DocumentSequence")
      @Column(name = "ID")
      private Long id;

      @OneToOne(mappedBy="document", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      private RequestDocument requestDocument;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "SAKREG_DOC_TYPE_ID_FK")
      private DocumentType documentType;
}
```

RequestDocument Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REQUEST_DOCS")
public class RequestDocument {
      @Id
      @SequenceGenerator(name = "requestDocSequence", sequenceName = "REQUEST_DOCS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "requestDocSequence")
      @Column(name = "ID")
      private Long id;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="SAKREG_REQUEST_ID")
      private Request request;

      @OneToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="SAKREG_DOC_ID")
      private Document document;
}
```

Request Entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "SAKREG_REQUEST")
    public class Request {
          @Id
          @SequenceGenerator(name = "requestIdSequence", sequenceName = "SAKREG_REQUEST_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "requestIdSequence")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @CmProperty(symbolicName = "RequestId")
    private Long id;
}
```

DocumentType Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SAKREG_DOC_TYPE")
public class DocumentType{
@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Short id;
}
```

So, How can I write the a delete statement which can delete a Document
with a RequestDocument with specific Request Id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate exception Query not properly ended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28695144/hibernate-exception-query-not-properly-ended)

Comment: Show the mapping and usage of `DocumentType`.

Comment: @Tobb DocumentType mapping & usage added

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use multiple tables in a delete statement like that.

Try rewriting the delete statement in using an exists.

```
@Query("delete from Document d where exists " +
" (select requestDocument from RequestDocument requestDocument " +
"  where requestDocument.request.id = :requestId " +
"  and requestDocument = d.requestDocument)" +
"  and d.documentType.lookupCode in (:documentTypeLookupCodes) ")
```